# Picking from isometric tiles using transformation matrices

Tags: matrix, libgdx, isometric

A really have no a problem(app is running), what I want is you help me understanding this

**The problem**
Pick from isometric tiles

**Conditions**
Use transformation matrices

**Reference**
[Reference tutorial](http://www.alcove-games.com/advanced-tutorials/isometric-tile-picking/)

**My understanding problem**(lol)
 I don't understand in the final part

```
touch.mul(invIsotransform);
```

Why the inverted matrix?

Comment: Correct = "A really have" for "I really have"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial describes the math for a transform that converts a point in Cartesian coordinates to a point in isometric coordinates. But when you touch the screen that is visually in isometric coordinates, you want to convert it back to Cartesian coordinates to easily pick the correct tile. Inverting the matrix produces a new matrix that does the opposite transformation of going from isometric to Cartesian.